# Javafx unit test for tableview checkboxes

Tags: javafx, junit

I am new to JavaFx, or to be more precise, I don't know how to Google for what I want. Currently, I am working in a Gradle project using JavaFx as the GUI. I have defined a tableview and couple of tablecolumns. In one tablecolumn, I populate it with checkboxes. Again, I don't know the terms since I just copied them from internet.

This is how I define the tablecolumn.

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Section, Boolean> enrollStatus;
```

There is an observableList. From what I know, it somehow can link with tableView magically.

```
private ObservableList<Section> observableSections = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

I initialize in my controller class as such:

```
@FXML
    public void initialize() {
        courseCode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Section, String>("courseCode"));
        sectionCode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Section, String>("sectionCode"));
        courseName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Section, String>("courseName"));
        instructorName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Section, String>("instructorName"));
        enrollStatus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Section, Boolean>("enrollStatus"));
        enrollStatus.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(enrollStatus));
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        enrollStatus.setEditable(true);
        tableView.setItems(observableSections);
    }
```

There is also a function in controller such that after I populate the tableView with Section, it will add listener to each checkbox.

```
void populateSectionsList(boolean addListener, List<Course> courses) {
    observableSections.clear();
    for (Course course : courses) {
        List<Section> sections = course.getSections();
        if (addListener) {
            for (Section section : sections) {
                if (section.getEnrollStatus() == false) { //if true, listener added already
                    section.enrollStatusProperty().addListener(
                        (observable, oldvalue, newvalue) -> {
                            if (oldvalue == false && newvalue == true) {
                                enrolledSections.add(section);

                            if (oldvalue == true && newvalue == false)
                                for (int i = 0; i < enrolledSections.size(); ++i)
                                    if (enrolledSections.get(i).getEnrollStatus() == false) {
                                        enrolledSections.remove(i);
                                        updateTimeTable();
                                    }
                            }
                    );
                    }
            }
        }
        observableSections.addAll(sections);
    }
}
```

Up to this point, all checkboxes in the tableView are dynamically allocated on the run, which means that they are not in the fxml file. Therefore, I can't perform the follow task in unit test:

```
 @Test
     public void testbuttonSfqEnrollCourse() {
         clickOn("#tabMain");
         clickOn("#buttonSearch");
         clickOn("#tabSfq");
         clickOn("#buttonSfqEnrollCourse");
     }
```

so my problem is, how to code in test file such that after pressing "test" in Gradle Task, it will pop up a window and automatically click the checkboxes in tableview?

Comment: It's not quite an answer to exactly what you're asking (and I don't unit test my views, other than with cheap manual labor (mine)), but you can simulate checking a check box by simply calling `setEnrollStatus(true)` on the corresponding `Section`. (The only code that ties the two things together is JavaFX library code, along with the single line `enrollStatus.setCellFactory(...)`.) Off-topic: the code in your listener appears to be structured incorrectly; the second `if(...)` is inside the first `if(...)`, and consequently can never be executed.